# How to remove field prefix of columns

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a database (mysql) in which every fields of tables starts with a letter followed by an underscore. For example if the table name is User all the field in the table will be named like U_NAME, U_SURNAME etc. If the table name is for example POST all the fields will be named as P_TITLE, P_DATE etc.

I'm using symsfony2 and is command line tools. So to generate the entities starting from the db  I used this  [guide](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html)
My problem is that doctrine generates the fields name as uName uSurname etc. so that when I try to generate a simple CRUD, the controller fails to retrive correct data beacuse it tries to use the function getId instead of the inside the model named getUId.
So I'm wondering if there some way to tell doctrine to ignore that prefix on the tables. I think it's not a good solution to change all the involved methods on the controllers.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is the easy way to do so. You can just rename entities properties `private $uId` -> `private $id`, then remove all the getters and setters and execute `doctrine:generate:entities YourBundle` to regenerate these methods based on renamed properties.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I didn't get what u mean. I have the entities only after the launch of doctrine:generate:entities. Do u meant that I have to launch the command twice: in the first launch it will generate default entities and in the second launch it will generate what I need?

Comment: Nope.  What Vadim means is that you need to edit all your generated entity files.  Or just write them by hand.